# Codeigniter : detail page is not showing any data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm still learning codeigniter, and i'm trying to create a detail page, so when i click on the detail button on a certain item, it will redirect the user to the detail page of that item. But when i click on it, i don't get any data. What did i do wrong??

The Controller :

```
public function detail($id){
$data['t_lowongan'] = $this->db->get_where('t_lowongan', array('id_lowongan'=>$id))->row_array();
$this->load->view('detail_lowongan', $data);
}
```

The detail view :

```
<div class="card-body">
 <?php foreach($t_lowongan as $lowong){?>
  <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $lowong->title?></h5>
 <?php }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
public function detail($id){
$data['t_lowongan'] = $this->db->get_where('t_lowongan', ['id_lowongan'=>$id])->result();
$this->load->view('detail_lowongan', $data);
}
```

and thats it!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i did is, i create the function in the model, the function is called detail_data.

The M_lowongan :

```
public function detail_data($where, $table){
        return $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
    }
```

After that i edit the controller look like this :

```
$where = array('id_lowongan'=>$id);
        $data['t_lowongan'] = $this->m_lowongan->detail_data($where, 't_lowongan')->result();

$this->load->view('detail_lowongan', $data);
```

And it works :D